# Implementation of subset sum problem is giving wrong answer

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, subset, subset-sum

I want to implement a solution for the subset sum problem. But in the below implementation all test cases are returning 'No'. Can someone point out the problem in the code?

```py
def isSubls(l, n, s):

    if s == 0:
        return 'Yes'
    if n == 0 and s != 0:
        return False
    if l[n - 1] > s:
        return isSubls(l, n - 1, s)

    return isSubls(l, n-1, s) or isSubls(l, n-1, s-l[n-1])


def run():

    for _ in range(int(input())):

        n, m = map(int, input().split())
        l = []

        for i in range(n):
            l.append(int(input()))

        print(isSubls(l, n, m))


run()
```

Comment: Could you explain what the inputs are and what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: Could you edit your question and give an example of your test cases so that we better understand what exactly you are working with, and hence, be better able to help?

Comment: Try to use variables with meaningful names. Since letters are rarely meaningful.

Comment: Is the problem with `isSubls()` or with generating your variables from your input? Can you verify the data generation is correct first, and if it does - remove it from the question to reduce noise?

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: Correct the source code to better conform with PEP8. Tried to make title and post more descriptive and easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `isSubls()` is completely correct.

I tested your code as follows:

```
def isSubls(l,n, s) : 
    if (s == 0) : 
        return True
    if (n == 0 and s != 0) : 
        return False 
    if (l[n - 1] > s) : 
        return isSubls(l, n - 1, s); 
    return isSubls(l, n-1, s) or isSubls(l, n-1, s-l[n-1]) 


set = [3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2] 
sum = 9
n = len(set) 
if (isSubls(set, n, sum) == True) : 
    print("Found a subset with given sum") 
else : 
    print("No subset with given sum")
```

**Verdict:**

[image]

Comment: If you change `if (isSubls(set, n, sum) == True)` to `if (isSubls(set, n, sum))` , the old code works perfectly as well. 'Yes' (or any other non empty string) is evaluated as `True` for such operations